# How to develop STB Middleware and which programming language is used

Tags: java, android, html

Need to know basic steps to take of how to develop Middleware for STB and which programming language is used and from where can i learn

Comment: "Middleware" is a vague term especially if you are referring to Set Top Box (STB) which could mean anything from a cable TV provider box or a Android TV box. You've tagged the question `Android` but you might be referring to non-Android boxes. Please edit your question with more info.

Comment: I am referring to both android and non android Boxes as such both include hardware programming so if you can help me with some info about the development of these it will be appreciable